# Rollback transaction rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rails-console

I have encountered a problem with my rails console when I try to create a new event based on a user. I have a feeling this is a very simple error that I am getting, but I am posting because I am unsure of how I should fix it. Here is the command I tried to run:

```
user.event = Event.create(:name => "Dummy")
```

Here is my db file for my event:

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my Users database file:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :event
      t.integer :code


      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my User.rb file:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password
    has_many :events

    def User.digest(string)
        cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST : BCrypt::Engine.cost
        BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
    end
end
```

Here is my Event.rb file:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no foreign key in your tables. Supposing you are actually intending to have the models as explained ("event belongs to user"/"user has many events"), you need to add a column `user_id` to the events table, and not an `event` string to the users table.

You can create a migration or column definition with migration/model generators using the `references` type:

```
rails g model event name:string user:references
```

or

```
rails g migration add_user_id_to_event user:references
```

which will add column and the needed indexes.

Moreover, you have that a user has *many* events, so there is nothing like

```
user.event = Event.create
```

(there is no such method as `User#event=`) but instead

```
user.events << Event.create(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not a simple error. It's quite a few things which are wrong.

If you want a relation where a user can have many events, and an event can belong to many users you need to create a join table. As storing a foreign key on either the users or events table would create a one to many relationship which is probably not what you want.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_events
  has_many :events, through: :user_events
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_events
  has_many :users, through: :user_events
end

# this is a join model.
class UserEvent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

> A `has_many :through association` is often used to set up a many-to-many
>   connection with another model. This association indicates that the
>   declaring model can be matched with zero or more instances of another
>   model by proceeding through a third model.
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

You can generate the `UserEvent` model and the migration which creates the join table by running:

```
rails g model user_event user:belongs_to event:belongs_to
```

This will create a `user_events` table with the `user_id` and `event_id` foreign key columns. You should also roll back the migration which creates the users table and fix it:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest # !!!
      t.integer :code
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Note the addition of the `password_digest` column - this is required for `has_secure_password`. If you have already run this migration on the production database or committed and pushed it you should instead create separate migrations which fix the errors:

```
class AddPasswordDigestToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column(:users, :password_digest, :string)
  end
end

class RemoveEventFromUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    remove_column(:users, :event)
  end
end
```

---

To create an event which is associated with a user you can do:

```
event = user.events.new(name: "Dummy") # does not persist the record
event = user.events.create(name: "Dummy")
```

You can all assign records from either end by using the shovel operator:

```
user.events << event
event.users << user
```

---

Is this the right association for me?

> My main goal for my application is to make it so a user has partys and 
>   those parties have songs.

A party with only one user sounds pretty lame. However if you want to create a special relationship for the user you can create a separate association:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_events
  has_many :events, through: :user_events
  has_many :owned_events, class_name: 'Event', foreign_key: 'owner_id' 
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_events
  has_many :users, through: :user_events
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
end

class AddOwnerIdToEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column(:events, :owner_id, :integer)
    add_foreign_key(:events, :users, column: :owner_id)
  end
end
```

Another way to solve this is by adding a column to `UserEvent` join model which specifies what the association is. But this is pretty far beyond your skill level.

Comment: Thanks for the very in depth discription of my problem. I ended up getting the associations to work. My final question is would this be assigning each user a event. My main goal for my application is to make it so a user has partys and those parties have songs. Am I going in the right direction for this application?

Comment: You should really read through the rails guides [article on associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) and the [active record query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables).

Comment: Okay, will do! :)